# Problem with Diophantine equations

Tags: diophantine-equations

A man purchases an item for 10.08 and instead of paying cash he tendered a cheque which he had with him. the cashier mistook the number of cents for the number of dollars and the number of dollars for the number of cents and gave back 7 times the value of the cheque as balance.

if A is the actual value of the cheque and
if D is the actual value of dollars and 
if c is the actual value of cents

i got these two equations
           A=D+100c
and for the cashiers calculation
          100D+c-10.08=7A
after solving above two you get 
          93D-699C=10.08
Using euclids i got 
     D=(-50.4) and C = (-6.72)

What should be done next to find the value of A?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to get negative values for $D$ and $C$ (or $c$, as you seem to switch from one to the other). But you can add $699t$ to $D$ and $93t$ to $C$ for arbitrary $t$ and still satisfy the equation (assuming you've done your calculations right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct equations are

$$\begin{align}
A&=D+{c\over100}\\
7A&=c+{D\over100}-10.08
\end{align}$$

This leads to

$$100c+D-1008=700A=700D+7c$$

which simplifies to

$$31c=233D+336$$

Note that $233D+336\equiv16D-5$ mod $31$, so we must have $D\equiv10$ mod $31$. The allowable values of $c$ (which cannot have more than two digits) are of the form

$$0\le c={233(10+31k)+336\over31}\lt100$$

i.e.

$$0\le c=233k+86\lt100$$

so we clearly have $k=0$, which means $D=10$ and $c=86$. This gives $A=\$10.86$ as the actual amount of the cheque.

Answer (score 0):

There’s an error in your second equation.

You need to *either* work in cents throughout :

$$
A = D + 100C\\
100D + C - 1008 = 7A
$$

*or* work in dollars :

$$
A = C + .01D\\
D + .01C - 10.08 = 7A
$$

If you carry on from here, you should get a sensible answer.